# Angular rxjs to rxjs 6 and rxjs-compat

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've tried issuing the following command:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

but I can't find the rxjs-compat folder. Anyway, here's the real problem:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, DebounceTime } from 'rxjs/Operator';
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.products$ = this.searchSubject
    .pipe(startWith(this.searchTerm), debounceTime(300));
}
```

This should be proper rxjs v6 code.  The error is "Property 'startWith' does not exist on type 'Subject'.ts

Can you advise?  I'm in a bit of a jam.  Thank you - Dale

Answer (score 2):

There are mistakes in the import: `import { startWith, DebounceTime } from 'rxjs/Operator';` should be `import { startWith, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';` (case sensitive and operators with a "s")